# Larger New Contributor warnings?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I can't see what new contributors get to see when posting their first question, so this is complete guesswork, but it would appear that the notification that, if your question is about your

## TV, HiFi or car stereo, it does not belong here!!

is all too frequently not seen, or just ignored.

Can we make this bit **louder** for those who still seem to get past it without seeing it?